# Regular expression for 24-hour format in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a scalar variable that I have some string value. Now I want to write a pattern match that checks whether the value is in the correct format or not.

```
my $var = "2340";
```

**Correct Format**

```
my $var ="23:40";
```

I tried this but not working for me:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d
```

Time can be of the format 00:00 (the format will be 2 digits before : and 2 digits after :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've contracted a case of regexitis, which is when a coder, upon discovering the powers of regular expressions, attempts to use them for *everything*, even situations in which they are very awkward and it would make much more sense to use something else.

In your case, off-the-cuff code (not tested, may have some syntax errors):

```
if($var =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d)/) {
    my $hour = $1; my $min = $2;
    if($hour > 23 || $min > 59) {
        print "Numbers out of range!";
    } else {
        #Yay, valid!
    }
} else {
    print "Invalid date format!";
}
```

Comment: how can we do this in jquery any idea u have ??

Comment: Regular expressions are very available in Javascript, there's a good overview of them [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2):

your regex seems to be build for a 12 hour clock not 24 hour clock, you can try the following instead:

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3])\:([0-5]\d)$
```

Comment: What about 20:30? You don't match the 20 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? just `/^\d\d:\d\d$/` should work to check for 2 digits

You can make it more complicated for better checking, like `[0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]` to check for valid digits. More validation than this should be done with regular code as cincodenada points out.